# Do Alaskan bush pilots generate a Clmax of 5 with 90° flaps?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

I understand the Alaskan bush pilots use 90° flaps in the Valdez STOL competition. I think this would stall the flaps. And if so, it wouldn't increase lift and reduce stall speed, but Javafoil says the opposite.

Perhaps this is more for lift/lower stall speed than drag. Since they land flat halfway down a long runway they don't need drag to slow down.

Just to do a test, I input a NACA 2415 foil in javafoil, 25% chord flap, 90 deg flaps deflection. And as expected, lots of drag, but Clmax jumps from 1.5 to 5 at about 0 deg AOA.

Is this realistic? If not, what is the real Clmax?

Comment: A STOL landing is typically best accomplished at high drag with power on. This is especially true of aircraft with a high power to weight ratio, as is typically the case in these competitions. The STOL landing technique will typically involve a higher than normal (e.g., greater than 3°) descent angle with a touchdown near, or even beyond, wing stall. Thus, the greater drag of greater flap extension likely aids in maximizing the short landing performance.

Comment: They actually land pretty flat WITH POWER OFF in this competition as it is in halfway down a runway and not a clearing surrounded by trees. It's really a test of short landing roll, rather than a typical STOL landing with a short approach and short landing.

Comment: To be clear; while this behaviour is most common amongst Alaskan bush pilots, other bush pilot subspecies around North America have been observed to use 90* flap deflection as well. Biologists believe this is a form of territorial display.

Comment: I'd say you are seeing oddball numbers because the effects of 90 deg flap are outside of javafoil's normal parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The following graph is from [Cahill, Summary of Section Data on Trailing-Edge High-Lift Devices](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19930092003&hterms=Data%20Trailing-Edge%20Devices&qs=N%3D0%26Ntk%3DAll%26Ntx%3Dmode%2Bmatchallany%26Ntt%3DData%2Bon%2BTrailing-Edge%2BDevices). As you can see, for a plain flap, with gaps fully sealed, the $C_{L_{max}}$ maxes out at around 60deg.

[image]

When I played around with xfoil, things became unreasonable beyond 40deg. Probably some assumptions in the boundary-layer equations broke down. Since Javafoil utilizes the same computational approach as xfoil, I would expect the same behavior.

On the Alaskan Bush pilots, are we sure they are 90deg deflection, and not just some high deflection that looks almost vertical? With multi-element, slotted flaps, you can do better than plain flaps.